# How to loop in python to target amount?

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty with the below problems and not sure what I'm doing wrong. My goal is to figure out how many periods I need to compound interest on a deposit using loops to reach a target deposit amount on a function that takes three arguments I have to create. I've included what I have below but can't seem to get my number of periods.

Example:
period(1000, .05, 2000) - answer 15
where d is initial deposit, r is interest rate and t is target amount.

```py
new_deposit = 0

def periods (d,r,t):
    while d*(1+r)<=t:
        new_deposit = d*(1+r) - d
        print(new_deposit)
    return periods
```

I'm very new to this so not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `d`, `r` and `t` never change. How do you expect the loop condition (`while d*(1+r)<=t:`, which is defined solely in terms of those three variables) to change if none of the inputs to it change?

Comment: You are returning 'periods' which is never set.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but your return statement would throw an error as you never set `periods`.

```py
def periods(d,r,t):
    count_periods = 1
    current_ammount = d
    while current_ammount*(1+r)<=t:
        current_ammount = current_ammount*(1+r)
        count_periods+=1
        print(current_ammount)
    return count_periods

print(periods(100, 0.01, 105))
```

I renamed the return variable, as to not overlap with the function name itself.

EDIT: sorry your logic was flawed all the way through the code, rewrote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def periods(d, r, t):
    p = 0
    while d < t:
        d *= (1 + r)
        p += 1
    return p

periods(100, .01, 105) # 5
```